# Add styling outside the border-radius

Tags: html, background, background-color, css

[image]

This is how my current header looks like. I want to edit it that the part in the picture below has the same color as the div next to it / the border. How can I do this?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/umoZGxW.png]

**Code on jsbin**: http://jsbin.com/ezeyib/3/

Comment: What is the question? its difficult to tell whats being asked here

Comment: Ya, tell us more about your problem.

Comment: I think i see what you mean now, why dont you just have the rounded title section overlapping two solid blocks?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, I wanted everything underneath the green line to be green aswell. @ShuklaJay

Comment: @Blowsie Cause that will mess up the background of the header, I want that to be transparent.

Comment: I see, as far as I know you cant do this with css3, you will need to use svg or a png etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by oversizing the border thickness and then setting the parents overflow to hidden.

See this example.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/ezeyib/5/edit

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I mean you need to create a png file using Photoshop or Illustrator to retrieve the expected result.

If you can have a plain background instead of a gradient background, you can create two big blocks (one green and one blue), and on top of those, create a shape with rounded corners which matches the actual look.